# What is the advantage of initializing an object with data types wrapped in comparitive symbols, e.g. greater than and less than?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, promise

I have two applications, one is written in TypeScript and the other in React. While replicating the functionality that exists now in TypeScript to develop a working version in React, the browser console throws syntax errors and babels on about a transpiler error.

Does react support syntax like: `Array<File>` or `<Array<File>>`? Please explain why or why not.

I see these symbols quite often in promise/observable code and now in this case for files. What purpose does instantiating an object in this manner serve, what advantage does it have over simply instantiating an empty array?

Comment: TypeScript is not used in React but it is used in Angular 2.

Comment: I am replicating old Angular 2 work I have, rewriting with react library.

Comment: @Tumen_t Plenty of people use TypeScript with React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax "types" the elements that can exist in the collection.

`Array<Employee>` will be an array of objects of type "Employee". If you try to put an object into that array that is not of type "Employee", you will get an error.

If you were to see this:

```
Array<Array<Employee>>
```

That would be an Array, that can only contain Arrays that contain objects of type Employee.

And so on. Note that you can use interfaces too:

```
Array<ISerializable>
```

"Any old thing" (depending on the language, I don't think every language that has this type feature has ?):

```
Array<?>, Array<any> (which I believe is the TS syntax)
```

And so on. Lots of languages use this.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. What would be an example of an interface you could use? I am having trouble visualizing that.

Comment: Any interface you could create, or that already exists. If you're not familiar with Interfaces in general, that's definitely an OOP concept you want to look up.

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 uses TypeScript while React uses normal Javascript. Like the name TypeScript says it is based on the **types** that makes your code more robust to develop since you cannot assign what ever items to your arrays (like Javascript allows) but they need to be **type of files**.

Answer (score 0):

Angled brackets are used in two contexts:

### Generic Types

In a type declarations for generic types. A generic type allows you to write a method like `RemoveObject<T>() : void`, where T is any specific type. This allows you to ensure type safety without knowing the type in advance. In this context, type can be any TypeScript type (interface, type aliases, classes, value types, etc).

Generics is a feature Microsoft seems to have lifted from C#, and is extremely powerful. You can read more about them [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and I *strongly* encourage you to read more about them.

### Type Casting

Casting a value to a different type. There are two ways to do this:

```
let obj : {} = {};
let stringed : string = obj as string; // Preferred Syntax
let stringed2 : string  = <string> obj; // Alternate Syntax
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, I wasn't aware of generics  before.

Comment: what is different when you cast with `let obj:{}={}` vs `let obj={}`?

Comment: @DanielO'Quinn so that's not a casting so much as it is declaring the object type during variable initialization. TS will normally try to infer the variable type from the value being assigned. You generally don't assign an empty object literal as a type, but you can declare a variable type when you want to ensure the inferred type is what you want it to be. [Here's some examples.](https://codesandbox.io/s/q8wq3qk4lw)